# The C define with any value for non zero

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In C I have a define like:

```c
#define VALUE 5
```

But the user can set a function too:

```c
#define VALUE get_value()
```

For historical reasons

```
#define VALUE 0
```

means "the value is not set, use the default"

The question is how to write an `#if` that decides if `VALUE` is `0`.

```c
#if VALUE == 0
 ...
#else
 ...
#endif
```

gives `"missing binary operator before token "(""` error with GCC.

---

EDIT:
To make the use case clearer:

```c
#if VALUE == 0
  set_default_value();
#else
  set_value(VALUE)
#endif
```

So I don't need `VALUE` to be evaluated in the `#if` just see if it's literally '0' or not.

Comment: If `VALUE` is defined as a function the precompiler cannot know its return value. So its not possible if `VALUE` can be defined as a function. Note that `#if...` are precompiler operations. It will be replaced with C-Code prior to compilation. Its nothing that gets evaluated during runtime, thus its purely static and can only handle static values.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Check the return value of the function during preprocessing (which is not possible), or verify if macro is defined to static value or a function (which can be achieved)?

Comment: As sergey pointed out in the answer, I used the wrong terminus, sorry. Of course its preprocessor, not precompiler... sorry about that!

Comment: `gives "missing binary operator before token "(""` The user has forgotten to define `get_value()` function macro, it's his fault.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I've updated my question with an example.

Comment: If you **need** to do this, then a way to do it is to create a source file that first includes whatever file(s) somebody might have defined `VALUE` in, then ends with a single line containing `VALUE`. Preprocess that file (`-E` switch to GCC or Clang). Examine the output (using some script you write) to see whether `VALUE` was not replaced, was replaced with `0`, or was replaced with something else. Proceed with your build accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic solution is likely impossible, but you can hack something together:

```
#define CAT(x, ...) CAT_(x, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CAT_(x, ...) x##__VA_ARGS__

#define CHECK_VALUE_CHECK_0 )(

#define CHECK_VALUE_FALSE(...) CHECK_VALUE_TRUE
#define CHECK_VALUE_TRUE() 1

#define CHECK_VALUE CHECK_VALUE_(CAT(CHECK_VALUE_CHECK_, VALUE))
#define CHECK_VALUE_(...) CHECK_VALUE_FALSE(__VA_ARGS__)

#if CHECK_VALUE
#error Value is 0.
#else
#error Value is not 0.
#endif
```

Now, if `VALUE` is defined to `0`, the macro `CHECK_VALUE` will expand to `1`. Otherwise it will expand to `CHECK_VALUE_TRUE`, which as an unknown identifier, is considered falsey by `#if`.

This solution is hacky:

- If `VALUE` starts with `0,`, its causes a hard error.
- If `VALUE` starts with something other than a letter or digit or `_` (e.g. `(`), it causes a hard error.
- ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use preprocessing pattern matching.

```
#define SECOND(...) SECOND_I(__VA_ARGS__,,)
#define SECOND_I(A,B,...) B

#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_I(A, B)
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B

#define ZERO_TEST(X_) SECOND(GLUE(ZERO_TEST_AGAINST_,X_),0)
#define ZERO_TEST_AGAINST_0 ,1
```

The key construct here is the `SECOND` macro, which indirectly expands to its second argument.  For pattern matching, you would use this by carefully constructing a first argument; since `SECOND` normally expands to its second argument, whatever you construct is normally ignored.  But since `SECOND` expands to its second argument *indirectly*, you can cherry pick a particular pattern by having the first argument expand in particular cases with a comma, which would shove in a new second argument.

In this case we have an indirect paste at the end of `ZERO_TEST_AGAINST_`, and we're looking for the result of that to be `ZERO_TEST_AGAINST_0`.

To use this:

```
#if ZERO_TEST(VALUE)
  set_default_value();
#else
  set_value(VALUE)
#endif
```

### Demo

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a6afc189637cfd3

### Caveat

This fits your spec precisely as given; the indirect paste would not work with this form if you have parenthetical definitions:

```
#define VALUE (5)
```

...or:

```
#define VALUE (get_value() << 2) | 1
```

...since `ZERO_TEST_AGAINST_` and `(` do not join to make a valid token.

Comment: Hmm nice. This fails at `0,` just like mine, but mine can handle `1,`.

Comment: Both this and HolyBlackCat's answers are amazing. Sad to hear that there is no elegant solution but in my case both work. 

This idea easier to follow for me but if HolyBlackCat's approach handles `1, ` too I think I should accept his answer. 

Thank you very much for the prompt help! :)

Comment: FYI, I don't think `0,` and `1,` are worth considering, since in this case `VALUE` is something that in principle will make `set_value(VALUE)` valid.  OTOH, both our solutions share the same core, and neither will work with negatives (e.g., `#define VALUE -1`); i.e., either approach would do, but this is another constraint (there may be more, but I'm too wonky to think of them all ATM; generally it's "pasteability" to the test token that's of concern).

Answer (score 0):

A preprocessor cannot evaluate C-Functions, such as `get_value()`. It can only handle static data, as its replaced with code prior to compilation, so your statements are not executed at runtime.

`if (VALUE == 0)` in your C-Code would get replaced for example with `if (get_value() == 0)` prior to compilation. The Preprocessor is not able to evaluate the return value of `get_value()` (even if it would always return 0).

Comment: There is no such thing as `precompiler`. It is called `preprocessor`.

Comment: You are abolutly right, ill correct it. Wrng terminus, sorry :D

Answer (score 0):

A `#define VALUE 5` line makes the C preprocessor replace the string `VALUE` with the string `5` wherever it sees it (outside "strings", that is). The resulting program will not even contain `VALUE` anymore, and that is what the compiler proper sees(1).

Do an experiment: Get your program (cut it down to a few lines), and run:

```
cc -E proggie.c > proggie.i
```

Under Unixy systems you'll get a file `proggie.i` that contains preprocessed C, which is what the compiler proper sees. No `VALUE` in sight, and trying to set `VALUE` in the source ends up as trying to set `0`, which obviously won't work.

(1) Historically, C compilers ran a chain of programs over the source (then memories where measured in KiB, not GiB), the first --preprocessor-- was usually called `cpp`; today's compilers usually don't have a separate preprocessor anymore. But conceptually the first step is still preprocessing the code (handle `#include`, `#if` and `#define`d macros).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstand how the historical 'the value is not set' works.

In the C preprocessor, whenever you have an `#if` directive *any* identifier in the expression that is not an macro (and is not the special function `defined`) will be replaced by the constant `0` prior to evaluating the `#if`.  So with your example

```
#define VALUE get_value()
#if VALUE == 0
```

what happens is the `VALUE` macro is expanded, then, since there is no `get_value` macro defined, it is replaced by `0`, leaving you with

```
#if 0() == 0
```

which gives you the syntax error you see.

Comment: Thank you, I really didn't understand the origin of the compiler error.