# Macro to determine whether another macro is set

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In my code I often have constructs like this:

```
#ifdef SOME_MACRO
int some_value=1;
#else
int some_value=0;
#endif

// ...


if (some_value)
{
    // ...
}
```

For clarity I would like to have something like this instead:

```
if (MACRO_IS_DEFINED(SOME_MACRO))
{
    // ...
}
```

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: #if defined( SOME_MACRO )  or #ifdef SOME_MACRO

Comment: Alternatively`#if SOME_MACRO == 1`, you can do arithmetic in the preprocessor.

Comment: In C++ please don't use macros this way. I'm sure the original and actual problem you're trying to solve (but don't tell us about, making your question an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)) can be solved without the use of macros. Probably even in C.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68074933/2752075 ?

Comment: What should happen on `#define SOME_MACRO SOMETHING_UNIQUE`? On `#define SOME_MACRO "text"`? Should `MACRO_IS_SET` return 1 or 0?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I hate macros as much as the next experienced programmer. The macros I'm interested in are set, or not, by the compiler, for example `__AVX2__` and I'd much rather use `if constexpr ()` than `#if` wherever I can.

Comment: Note there was an error when I posted the question: I had `#if` in the example, I can see how that looks like bad practice.

Comment: That's totally different, and would have been excellent information inside the question itself. That's why it's so important to make sure all the details are in the question, together with the actual problem you're trying to solve. And of course with a proper [mre]. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is easily reproducible and in my opinion question is clear and concise. If there is an answer it could be very useful to others. By the way, I'm happy with "it's not possible" as an answer.

Comment: The top answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464170/using-definedmacro-inside-the-c-if-statement allows you to make a statement which is true if the given macro is defined to a specific value and false otherwise. I.e. you can test if a given macro is defined and equal to e.g. "1" (that is the value used in the answer, but it can easily be changed or expanded to a set of values), but it will not allow you to test if a given macro is defined with an arbitrary value.

Comment: Nice find @nielsen, thank you. Yes I think the macros I'm interested in are set to 1 so this could work. But, man, the solution is ugly!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using defined(MACRO) inside the C if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464170/using-definedmacro-inside-the-c-if-statement)

Comment: Since the evaluation of a macro is at compile time and the evaluation of a conditional is at runtime, you are asking for an ugly thing. Anyway, this looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @thebusybee the evaluation of this sort of conditional happens at compile time unless you are using C/C++ without `constexpr` and you have optimisations off. The advantage of using `if` instead of `#if` is that inactive code at least gets compiled so it gets a degree of protection from bitrot if it's not tested. Also it removes need for the `#if` and `if` combination you often see.

Comment: @thebusybee that answer does work, if my macro is defined to be "1" or other known string. I'd accept it as close enough, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

General best practice is to keep pre-processor "compiler switches" (#ifdef) and other such pre-processor tricks away from the application logic, ideally by centralizing it to the top of the .c file or placing it in some suitable header. Or to handle different versions of the program by external version control and not by the pre-processor.

In this case it could be something like:

```
#if defined(SOME_MACRO) && SOME_MACRO
  #define SOME_MACRO_IS_SET 1
#else
  #define SOME_MACRO_IS_SET 0
#endif
```

And then `if(SOME_MACRO_IS_SET)`.

Comment: Agreed, and this may be what I'll do although I'll use static const variables instead of new defines.. This doesn't answer my question though - I want a preprocessor function  (I have a feeling the answer will be it's impossible). Note I just fixed an error in the question, I meant to say `#ifdef` in the example, not '#if`.

Comment: @paperjam Adding additional constraints to the answer in comments is not the best way to go about things. Better to update your question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @super, I'm just saying that this answer is helpful, but doesn't actually answer the question. It doesn't give me a `MACRO_IS_DEFINED()`

Comment: @paperjam The first sentence of the answer actually does just that. The answer to "how do I secure a screw with a hammer" is "don't use a hammer, it's the wrong tool". You'd have to clutter down the application code with `#ifdef` which should be avoided.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to avoid, @Lundin. I want my application code to be super clean with just `if constexpr(MACRO_IS_DEFINED(SOME_MACRO))`. Turns out, I think, that it's impossible to write a simple `MACRO_IS_DEFINED` macro.  Edit: to your analogy, the answer is "make sure it stays straight and hit it harder than you would a nail, btw, have you tried a screwdriver?".

Comment: @paperjam Yes it is impossible since you cannot use other preprocessor directives inside a `#define` function-like macro.